# Jquery steps + async call making server call every time on step changes

Tags: jquery-steps

I am using `Jquery stpes plugin` for wizard.
Here I have one problem, On step 2 I am making ajax call to get the data and filling into input controls but the problem here is data is refreshing everytime on step changes. so state is not maintain. I have set the `enableCacheContent=true`, still it's not working.

```
form.steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",           
        enableContentCache: true})
```

Comment: what do you mean not working. please add the problem (errors you might get)

Comment: every time its getting data from server.So,state is not maintaing on step change.I want only on first time it will call  to server,Once data loaded,on step out or come again from other steps,It should not make any server call

Answer (score 0):

You can save response data in local variable, and check if the data exist in variable does not make request again